# Is Amazon Web Services reasonably priced for a personal server?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I currently have a Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP, Postfix web server that I setup on a spare computer at home that I am exploring transferring to Amazon Web Services. It's about as simple of a personal web server as it gets, I mainly use it for personal experimentation for PHP development, I have a blog, it hosts my e-mail, plus I do some C++ development on the server and run some small executable and networked personal applications.

The only traffic the server really sees is me (on a daily basis), plus some web crawlers, and the occasional hit from a Google search.

Is it reasonable to transfer my server to Amazon Web Services? Or is Amazon Web Services specifically targeted to larger scale servers? What's about the cheapest cost I can expect to pay for this hosting?

I tried using the [AWS Simple Monthly Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html) but had a hard time estimating the numbers. Perhaps someone is doing something similar to my plans, and can inform me of what they are paying.

One of the reasons I am interested in AWS, is I am contemplating using my website as cloud storage for a mobile application I am working on, and if that application takes off quickly, I would like to be able to quickly scale to the traffic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need a simple setup, it is sufficient to use a `t1.micro` instance. The monthly price for such an instance (depending on the location of the server) is about 15 US$. If you plan to run your server for a longer time, consider using reserved instances. You pay a one-time fee and get reduced hourly prices afterwards. If you run your server all the time, you should use a "High Utilization" instance. I think you won't get a lot of traffic and EBS requests, so I would focus on the main part regarding costs which is the EC2 instance hours.

Here is a basic [example calculation](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html?key=calc-B70AA43F-56E6-424E-8207-426C77675C91) with the above setup as a start. This calculation does not include a 1-year-free trial that Amazon offers.

If you need to scale, then you have a lot of options available. You can launch bigger instances if you need it. Have a look at the [instance types](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) page to get an overview (also includes details on the Micro instance). If scaling and possible upgrades are a main factor in your decision, then you should consider AWS.

Comment: Yes, I think the "High Utilization" instance best matches how I use my server. With a micro instance the cost amortized over a year is $12.49 / mo which I think is reasonable. Though the old computer I am using as a server currently is more equivalent to a medium instance, which would have a amortized cost of $59.58 / mo.

Comment: I found the following links helpful in explaining the terms:

[Utilization Explanation](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/)

[Instance Explanation](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)

[EC2 Compute Unit Explanation](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#What_is_an_EC2_Compute_Unit_and_why_did_you_introduce_it)

Answer (score 2):

`Is it reasonable to transfer my server to Amazon Web Services`

I think yes. Amazon has list of Linux versions where you can fetch **free** server with no payment. Bear in mind that, for example, for free server DB you can't connect to your DB from external IP (aka from external DB tool). But port redirection will work.

Usually I use Amazon for demo versions ( < 10k users). But its work great.